# How to make a Python property object that updates exclusively when needed?

Tags: python, properties, getter

I have a class that has a combination of attributes that are related to each other:

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self):
    self._x = 5


  @property
  def y(self):
    return fancy_function(self._x)
```

fancy_function is computationally expensive. 
I would like to have a way to store the result of y somewhere I can access without having to run fancy_function every time I do (sort of the equivalent of not needing to recompile C++ code if the dependencies are up to date). I could add an attribute self._y, but how can I ensure it stays updated with self._x. My best idea so far is to write:

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self):
    self._x = 5
    self._last_x = self._x
    self._y = fancy_function(self._x)


    @property
    def y(self):
      if self._last_x is not self._x:
        self._y = fancy_function(self._x)
      return self._y
```

And I guess it works, but I suspect there might be a cleaner way that doesn't require this additional attribute. Plus, if the user tries to directly access self._y, there is no guarantee it will be up to date with self._x

Is there a nice way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: "Plus, if the user tries to directly access self._y" - if they do that, it's their fault.

Comment: Make `MyClass._x` a property that updates `MyClass._y` when it's assigned to.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Huh.. That's pretty simplistic, I guess I didn't think of it that way. Thank you! Although it seems a little bizarre to update other properties in _x's assignment, but it's better than what I have so far.